# Nested list in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

How to create a nested lists in Yii2? 
Not a menu lists.
I followed [Yii2 docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-html#lists).

So, in `params.php` in config directory I have an array. 
The code is like this:

```
<?php
return [
'version' => 'framework: ' . Yii::getVersion() . ' version: ' . '0.0.0',
'description' => [
    'app' => [
        'PT. ABC' => [
            'feature' => [
                'Request IT-06',
                'PEB'
            ],
            'bug' => [
                'No Bug'
            ],
            'changelog' => [
                'Initialize Program'
            ]
        ],
        'PT. XYZ' => [
            'feature' => [
                'Request IT-06',
                'PEB'
            ],
            'bug' => [
                'No Bug'
            ],
            'changelog' => [
                'Initialize Program'
            ]
        ],
    ],
],
];
```

I want to make a nested lists. I just know to display the index of array like this:

```
-PT. ABC
-PT. XYZ
```

This is my code:

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Welcome to <?= Yii::$app->params['version'] ?></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?= Html::ul(Yii::$app->params['description']['app'], [
                'item' => function ($item, $index) {
                    return Html::tag(
                        'li',
                        $index,
                        ['class' => 'post']
                    );
                }
            ]) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need Like this,for example,

```
-PT. ABC
  * feature
     - feature 1
  * bug
  * changelog
-PT. XYZ
  * feature
  * bug
  * changelog
```

Comment: you can do using for loop

Answer (score 1):

You need a recurrency for this. Create your own `Html` helper with method for that:

```
public static function nestedUl($items) {
    return Html::ul($items, [
        'encode' => false,
        'item' => function ($item, $index) {
            if (is_array($item)) {
                $content = Html::encode($index) . Html::nestedUl($item);
            } else {
                $content = Html::encode($item);
            }

            return Html::tag(
                'li',
                $content,
                ['class' => 'post']
            );
        }
    ]);
}
```

It will generate nested list for each array.